# Ensuring unique elements in array created from merging 2 bigint arrays

Tags: arrays, postgresql, duplicates, bigint, postgresql-performance

What is the most efficient way to ensure the uniqueness of values in a `bigint` array created from merging of 2 other `bigint` arrays?

For example, this operation `select ARRAY[1,2] || ARRAY[2, 3]` should give as a result `1,2,3`. I have checked the extension [`intarray`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html) and see it does not work with `bigint`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write your own function for that.

```
create function concat_unique(p_array_one bigint[], p_array_two bigint[])
  returns bigint[]
as
$$
select array_agg(x order by x)
from (
  select x
  from unnest(p_array_one) as t(x)
  union
  select x
  from unnest(p_array_two) as t(x)
) t
$$
language sql
immutable;
```

And then:

```
select concat_unique(array[1,2], array[2,3,4]);
```

returns

```
concat_unique
-------------
{1,2,3,4}
```

Comment: Is it an effective operation? The arrays that I merge mostly not so big about 20 - 30 items in each. Let's say up to 100 items each in extreme case.

Comment: I don't see an alternative, so yes that "effective".

Answer (score 4):

Since you ask for ***efficient*** - the function can be optimized:

Nothing in your question demands sorted output. So:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_merge_uniq(bigint[], bigint[])
  RETURNS bigint[] AS
$func$
SELECT ARRAY(
  SELECT unnest($1)
  UNION
  SELECT unnest($2)
   )
$func$  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

But you can have that sorted, too, at practically no added cost:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_merge_uniq_sort(bigint[], bigint[])
  RETURNS bigint[] AS
$func$
SELECT ARRAY(
   SELECT DISTINCT x
   FROM (
      SELECT unnest($1)
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT unnest($2)
      ) sub(x)
   ORDER BY 1
   )
$func$  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4620bca22ca4e60a1c76054a8dd74bc2)*

Close to **twice as fast** in planning and execution for multiple reasons:

- If you `UNION` and *later* `ORDER BY`, Postgres does extra work.
  Sorting per result row with (`array_agg(x order by x)`) is the worst case. It's even slower for just one result row (like in this case) because there is more overhead. Sorting in the subquery (where possible) is typically more efficient:

  - [Is it REALLY possible that the order will not be guaranteed for this particular redundant derived table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/185862/3684)
- The `DISTINCT` operation can be based on a sort right away. My second function `f_merge_uniq_sort()` achieves that, so it's practically as fast as the first `f_merge_uniq()` even though it returns sorted arrays. (Seems to be even a bit faster in my tests with Postgres 12! Seems that `UNION` is slightly less efficient than `DISTINCT`.)
- An `ARRAY` constructor is faster than `array_agg()`.

  - [Why is array_agg() slower than the non-aggregate ARRAY() constructor?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/159717/3684)

Comment: Thanks for a very helpful explanation